# Is there a way to run a program and kill every 20 seconds in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command, execute

I have a program that i need to collect 300 pieces of data from, but to manually do the collecting i have to run the program on my ubuntu virtual machine and record the data on excel. It takes a long time to do this whole process. I was wondering if there was a command in linux that i could use to call commands make and to kill me program.
I search watch and tried it but it doesnt work for me:

> watch -n 20 make play

where make play runs my program

Yet this doesnt fo everything i want to do. I want to do this every 20 seconds so i have enough time to write my data to my excel file
1. make play (run my program so it prints what i need to record)
2. kill my program

Is there a command for this?

Comment: You should try `conjob`.

Comment: You got the syntax wrong  **watch -n 20 'make play'**.

Comment: still doesnt seem to be working, i mean it works but i cant see the printout jobs but i know the process is running when i use watch

Comment: i think i research more about cronjob and cron

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink what you are doing - I can't think of a setting where running and killing a program every 20 seconds makes any sense.

That being said, the standard way to run programs periodically in linux is a cron job. Cron has a 1 minute minimum though, so you would have to write a script that starts 3 instances of your program with 20 second delay, and run this script with cron every minute. You can combine this with the timeout utility, which will kill your program if it is still running after a given time. A quick google search should provide you with further details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Could use crontab, man crontab to get the manual of crontab. However, you may not be able to run and kill every 20s, at least every 1 min. Hope It could help.